# Add custom category type column to an Excel 2016 Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

Used the power query feature of Excel 2016 to import several CSV files containing personal financial history and trying to use the power pivot thing.

Problem is I really need to group the transactions by a category, but there is no such thing in the source files. I really don't want to add this to the source files, as they are autogenerated from my bank, or manually select and group things afterwards.

So, is there any way to add a step in the power query editor which would add a new column with a value based on a text field and using some sort of a switch/match/map function?

In pseudo code I'm thinking something like this:

```
if [Column] in {"foo", "bar", "baz"} return "Cat A"
if [Column] starts with "blah" return "Cat B"
if [Column] matches /\d+/ return "Cat C"
else return No Cat
```

Alternatively if there's any other good way of solving this...

---

**Sample data**

```
╔══ Date ════╦══ Text ═══════════════════════════╦══ Amount ═╦══ (new) ══╗
║ 01.05.2014 ║ Boots Apotek Bogstadvn.34 Oslo    ║ -289,70   ║ Health    ║
║ 01.05.2014 ║ 143 Boots Apotek Skøyen           ║ -73,00    ║ Health    ║
║ 01.05.2014 ║ Rema Industriga Industrigata Oslo ║ -25,70    ║ Groceries ║
║ 30.09.2014 ║ Råh Avd Industr Industrigt 4 Oslo ║ -575,00   ║ Hair      ║
║ 30.09.2014 ║ Random stuff                      ║ -68,00    ║ Other     ║
║ 30.09.2014 ║ Rema Industriga Industrigata Oslo ║ -39,90    ║ Groceries ║
║ 29.09.2014 ║ To Church Betel                   ║ -200,00   ║ Offering  ║
║ 29.09.2014 ║ To Church Cornelius               ║ -200,00   ║ Offering  ║
║ 29.09.2014 ║ To Johnny Landlord                ║ -9 015,00 ║ Rent      ║
║ 29.09.2014 ║ To Johnny Landlord                ║ -500,00   ║ Other     ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

So for example I'd want

- Health if text contains one of "Boots Apotek" or other pharmacy names
- Groceries if text starts with Rema or starts with/contains another store name
- Offering if text contains one of a list of church names
- Rent if text contains name of landlord *and* amount is greater than -9000, because anything below that is most likely something else

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data. See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Right, added some now, and also examples of the type of matching I'd want.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have a coder's approach, you can "Add a column" and write a lengthy nested if statement to resolve this, using a few PQ functions.  It would look something like this:

`if Text.Contains ( "foo|bar|baz|" , [Column] & "|" ) then "Cat A"
else if Text.StartsWith( [Column] , "blah" ) then "Cat B"
else if not ( ( try Number.From ( [Column] ) otherwise null ) is null ) then "Cat C"
else "No Cat"`

Answer (score 0):

Add a "Conditional Column".  This provides a rules engine based on data from other columns and should do what you want.