# How to Add custom Categories to Transaction Descriptions in an Excel Data Model

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, powerpivot

TL;DR: **(How)Can I create a pivot table from a data model in Excel where I can add custom text to that table, and then feed that modified pivot table back into the Data model?**

**Background:**

I am new to BI and experimenting with Power Query/Pivot/View in excel 2016. With my experimentation I am trying to consolidate and analyze a whole bunch of csv's downloaded from my bank. Not unlike a [previous and related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1021075/add-custom-category-type-column-to-an-excel-2016-power-query) I want to be able to add a category based off of the "Transaction description". However I would like to avoid writing a long conditional statement in PowerQuery that adds a calculated column when the Data is imported. I also do not want to modify the source csv's as they are being downloaded from my bank.

My plan was to create a pivot table that lists each **Unique** Transaction Description, then add a column to that table where I can enter the category next to each unique transaction description. Then once I had manually entered the category I would [add this new table to the Data Model](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/tutorial-extend-data-model-relationships-using-excel-power-pivot-and-dax-cf7197d3-1938-490e-93fb-20371e8dd67a)<sup>1</sup>.

My reasoning for trying to create this is I wish to make it easier to categorize transactions when I download and add new CSVs as the months go on. My hope is that when I add a new months data previously categorized transaction descriptions will be automatically set and new transaction descriptions will be easy to identify and categorize (as they will show up blank on the table).

**Sample data**

```
╔══ Date ════╦══ Transaction Description ════════╦══ Amount ═╦══ Cata. ══╗
║ 01.01.2019 ║ eTransfer-JoeLL                   ║ -900.00   ║ Rent      ║
║ 01.01.2019 ║ Foodbasics                        ║ -55.00    ║ Food      ║
║ 01.02.2019 ║ eTransfer-JoeLL                   ║ -900.00   ║ Rent      ║
║ 18.02.2019 ║ Foodbasics                        ║ -75.00    ║ Food      ║
║ 20.02.2019 ║ El Fancy Rest.                    ║ -25.00    ║ Food      ║
║ 01.03.2019 ║ eTransfer-JoeLL                   ║ -900.00   ║ Rent      ║
║ 04.03.2019 ║ Canada Computers                  ║ -100.00   ║ Other     ║
║ 04.03.2019 ║ Tim H #22                         ║ -10.15    ║ Food      ║
║ 01.04.2019 ║ eTransfer-JoeLL                   ║ -900.00   ║ Rent      ║
║ 02.04.2019 ║ eTransfer-JoeLL                   ║ -200.00   ║ Rent      ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Related question: [Add custom category type column to an Excel 2016 Power Query](https://superuser.com/questions/1021075/add-custom-category-type-column-to-an-excel-2016-power-query).

<sup>1</sup>My hope is to eventually add a hierarchy, eg: multiple categories so "Foodbasics" would be "Food" and "Grocery", and "Tim H#22" would be "Food" and "Breakfast". But that is out of scope for this Q as I figured it best to start simple.

Comment: I am still really new to Power Query/Pivot/View so let me know if anything isn't clear or if there is any more information you may need in order to answer the question.

Comment: Can you move this to Power BI? There you could take advantage of more advanced features e.g. Grouping https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-grouping-and-binning

Comment: @MikeHoney Unfortunately no, I do not have access to Power BI or Power BI Desktop. That is actually how this experimentation started as my workplace has started using Power BI and I wanted to try something similar with the (older) Power "suite" in excel. I have excel at home, but it is unlikely that I will get Power BI access at my workplace (not required for my job).